# How to do steps of an API through CLI/ batch mode without GUI

Tags: api, command-line-interface

I'm using Audiveris API to generate xml(MusicXML) file once the sheetmusic(e.g. pdf/img file) is being input (i.e. When I give the sheet music (pdf file) location, to generate the xml file out of it (in another location)).

Audiveris has its own GUI to do this. But can I do this process of sheetmusic-to-xml without using their GUI, but only from the CLI?
If so how may I approach it? And also if so - is there a possibility to make it work in CLI - using Java code (say to invoke steps for API to occur in the CLI using Java Code - I've heard this is possible using shell commands)?

I managed to open the GUI by opening the jar file from CLI. But I need to know whether there's a possibility to carry out the entire sheetmusic(say pdf)-to-xml process without using their GUI, but only through CLI (i.e. in batch mode)?

Greatly appreciate any help or guidance 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the -batch option and the program will run without the GUI.

Use the -help option, to get the full list of parameters for the CLI interface
For example:
    java -jar dist/audiveris-3.3.jar -help
will give you (reformatted for better readability):
 omr.CLI.stopUsage(CLI.java:362) -- INFO:

Audiveris options syntax:
[-help]
[-batch]
[-step STEPNAME]
[-option (KEY=VALUE|@OPTIONLIST)+]
[-sheet (SHEETNAME|@SHEETLIST)+]
[-script (SCRIPTNAME|@SCRIPTLIST)+]

Known step names are in order (non case-sensitive) :
LOAD        : Load the sheet picture
SCALE       : Compute global Skew and rotate if needed
SKEW        : Detect & remove all Staff Lines
LINES       : Retrieve horizontal Dashes
HORIZONTALS : Detect horizontal dashes
SYSTEMS     : Retrieve Systems from Bar sticks
MEASURES    : Retrieve Measures from Bar sticks
SYMBOLS     : Recognize Symbols & Compounds
VERTICALS   : Extract verticals
PATTERNS    : Specific sheet glyph patterns
SCORE       : Translate glyphs to score items
PLAY        : Play the whole score
MIDI        : Write the output MIDI file
EXPORT      : Export the score to MusicXML file

Comment: Yet, there's another issue with Audiveris 3.3 - it gives an error 'Cannot Load Zong Language', when trying to run the .bat or .jar file. Audiveris 3.3 uses ZongPlayer, and even though the data/lang folder of ZongPlayer is copied to the audiveris/dist folder of Audiveris, still the error remains. Do inform, if any one who figures out a solution for this.